# Why does java gives odd results while trying to find out the value of pi using java.math.BigInteger?

Tags: java, math, biginteger, pi, computation

I am trying to compute the value of pi by counting the number of points which may be there in circumference using the equation:

If the point of Circumference is (c<sub>x</sub>,c<sub>y</sub>),
and the radius is r:
then,
r<sup>2</sup> = c<sub>x</sub><sup>2</sup>+c<sub>y</sub><sup>2</sup>

But when I implement it in java using the following code:

```
package ani.pi.gen;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;

/**
 *
 * @author ani
 */
public class Engine {
private BigInteger x,pimag;
private final BigInteger radius;
public Engine(int digits){
    radius=new java.math.BigInteger("10").pow(digits);
    pimag=new BigInteger("0");
    x=new BigInteger("-"+radius);
    System.out.println(x+" "+radius);
}
public int percent=0;
private int lp=0;
public void start(){
    Thread t=new Thread(() -> {
        for(;x.compareTo(radius)<=0;x=x.add(new BigInteger("1"))){
            System.out.println(x.pow(2));
            for(BigInteger y=new BigInteger(""+radius);y.compareTo(radius)>=0;y=y.subtract(new BigInteger("1"))){
                if(x.pow(2).add(y.pow(2)).equals(radius.pow(2))){
                    pimag=pimag.add(new BigInteger("1"));
                    System.out.println(pimag+" "+x+" "+y);
                }
            }
            percent=(x.add(radius).divide(radius.multiply(new BigInteger("2")))).multiply(new BigInteger("100")).intValueExact();
            if(percent!=lp){
                System.out.println(percent+"%");
                lp=percent;

            }

        }
        System.out.println("Pi -> "+new BigDecimal(pimag.toString()).divide(new BigDecimal(radius+"")));
    });
    t.start();

}
}
```

When I run the program using the code:

```
new Engine(2).start();
```

I get the following output:

run:

> -100 100 10000 9801 9604 9409 9216 9025 8836 8649 8464 8281 8100 7921 7744 7569 7396 7225 7056 6889 6724 6561 6400 6241 6084 5929 5776 5625
>   5476 5329 5184 5041 4900 4761 4624 4489 4356 4225 4096 3969 3844 3721
>   3600 3481 3364 3249 3136 3025 2916 2809 2704 2601 2500 2401 2304 2209
>   2116 2025 1936 1849 1764 1681 1600 1521 1444 1369 1296 1225 1156 1089
>   1024 961 900 841 784 729 676 625 576 529 484 441 400 361 324 289 256
>   225 196 169 144 121 100 81 64 49 36 25 16 9 4 1 0 1 0 100 1 4 9 16 25
>   36 49 64 81 100 121 144 169 196 225 256 289 324 361 400 441 484 529
>   576 625 676 729 784 841 900 961 1024 1089 1156 1225 1296 1369 1444
>   1521 1600 1681 1764 1849 1936 2025 2116 2209 2304 2401 2500 2601 2704
>   2809 2916 3025 3136 3249 3364 3481 3600 3721 3844 3969 4096 4225 4356
>   4489 4624 4761 4900 5041 5184 5329 5476 5625 5776 5929 6084 6241 6400
>   6561 6724 6889 7056 7225 7396 7569 7744 7921 8100 8281 8464 8649 8836
>   9025 9216 9409 9604 9801 10000 100% Pi -> 0.01 BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total
>   time: 0 seconds)

Which states the value of pi is 0.01.

What maybe the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: I don't see the variable `pimag` ever being used in such a way that it would be set to Pi in your code.

Comment: Indeed - you seem to have assumed a big jump between the equation you posted and "computing pi". If you believe that `BigInteger` is behaving oddly, perhaps you have a specific computation in mind?

Comment: (As an aside, I'd also suggest using whitespace and constants for frequently-used BigInteger values to vastly increase the readability. And I don't see any reason to use threads just to demonstrate this problem.)

Comment: pimag is incremented every time when the equation, r^2 = cx^2+cy^2 is satisfied.

Comment: so what other equation can i use to compute pi? it seems that this equation cannot be implemented  using BigInteger or I dont know how to.

Comment: Your approach will not work.  Imagine you have a sheet of graph paper, and you draw a circle on it.  If I understand your algorithm correctly, it will count the number of points where the circle **exactly** goes through a point where a vertical line and horizontal line cross.  And there won't be that many.  You're counting the number of **integer** solutions to the equation `x^2+y^2=r^2`, where `r` is given, and the number of solutions will have no correlation with the circumference of the circle.  (Example: if r=5 there are 8 solutions, if r=6 there are only 4.)

Comment: @aniruddha.sarkar do you need _exact_ pi? Look for formulas at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_%CF%80

Comment: Actually, I have never heard of anyone trying to compute pi by "counting the number of points on the circumference of a circle" (which doesn't make sense anyway, since the number of points is infinite).  I don't think there's a way to make this work.

Comment: If r=5 there are 12 solutions, not 8.  My mistake.

Comment: @aniruddha.sarkar You almost got it. Look at the second for it must be `for (BigInteger y = new BigInteger("" + radius); y.compareTo(new BigInteger("-"+radius)) >= 0; y = y.subtract(new BigInteger("1")))`. Look at line  `if(x.pow(2).add(y.pow(2)).equals(radius.pow(2))){` it should contain `compareTo` as you must take those that lie inside the circle, not only on the circle. Must be `if (x.pow(2).add(y.pow(2)).compareTo(radius.pow(2)) <= 0)`. And the area calculated from `System.out.println("Pi -> " + new BigDecimal(pimag.toString()).divide(new BigDecimal(radius.pow(2) + "")));`. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost got it. Look at the second `for` it must be

```
for (BigInteger y = new BigInteger("" + radius); 
     y.compareTo(new BigInteger("-"+radius)) >= 0; 
     y = y.subtract(new BigInteger("1")))
```

Look at line

```
if(x.pow(2).add(y.pow(2)).equals(radius.pow(2))){
```

it should contain `compareTo` as you must take those that lie inside the circle, not only on the circle. Must be

```
if (x.pow(2).add(y.pow(2)).compareTo(radius.pow(2)) <= 0).
```

The area must be calculated with `radius.pow(2)`

```
System.out.println("Pi -> " + new BigDecimal(
                                 pimag.toString()).divide(
                                 new BigDecimal(radius.pow(2) + "")));
```

I tweaked your solution. :)

```
package javaapplication38;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

public class JavaApplication38
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {        
        new Engine(BigInteger.TEN.pow(2)).start();
    }

    public static class Engine
    {        
        final BigInteger radius    ;
        final BigInteger negRadius ;
        final BigInteger r2        ; //The force awakens on December 18, 2015.

        public static final BigInteger TWO = new BigInteger("2");    

        public Engine(BigInteger radius)
        {
            this.radius = radius;
            negRadius   = radius.negate();
            r2          = this.radius.pow(2);
        }

        public Engine(int radius)
        {
            this(new BigInteger("" + radius));
        }      

        public void start()
        {
            Runnable r = new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {                    
                    BigInteger area = BigInteger.ZERO; //area of the circle

                    //calculate circle's area
                    //let's walk through all the points (x;y)
                    for (BigInteger x = new BigInteger(negRadius.toString());
                            x.compareTo(radius) <= 0; 
                            x = x.add(BigInteger.ONE))
                    {                        
                        for (BigInteger y = new BigInteger(negRadius.toString());
                                y.compareTo(radius) <= 0;
                                y = y.add(BigInteger.ONE))
                        {
                            //System.out.format("Point %s, %s%n", x.toString(), y.toString());
                            //if square is in the circle add square's area to the area of the circle
                            if (x.pow(2).add(y.pow(2)).compareTo(r2) <= 0)
                            {
                                area = area.add(BigInteger.ONE);
                            }                            
                        }                        
                    }                    
                    System.out.println("Radius " + radius.toString());
                    System.out.println("Area " + area.toString());                    
                    System.out.println("PI   " + new BigDecimal(area).divide(new BigDecimal(r2)));                                                             
                }
            };
            new Thread(r).start();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Area 3141549
PI 3.141549
```